# libz.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 - Need to install the 64 bit package for zlib

Tags: apt, 64-bit, packaging

I am getting this error when compiling:

```
libz.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

From what I read online this happens when a directory which the script is calling is 32 bit and the script is looking for 64 bit library file.

So, I need to install a 64 bit package zlib.

The Ubuntu version is below:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04

DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"

Linux 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How to install the 64 bit package for zlib ?

Comment: Also `uname -a` - is your release 32 or 64 bit? And in addition, any details about your compilation (command used etc).

Comment: @ArturMeinild updated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue below on Ubuntu bionic (18.04LTS)

```
libz.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

---

**What I did:**

To install the 64 bit of lib64z1 package:

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get -y  install lib64z1
3. ll /usr/lib64/libz.so.1   <- the file will automatically be put here on install.

You should see:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Aug 16 22:08 /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
```

4. Add path to environment variable -> **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** so that the script knows where to find 64 bit version of this file -> libz.so.1

> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/`

This link was helpful: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/lib64z1/filelist